# Activemq STOMP: detecting and clearing dead nondurable subscribers

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp

I have the following situation that is affecting our ActiveMQ 5.8 broker.

Several Perl scripts on a Windows workstation connected to ActiveMQ using STOMP and subscribed (nondurable) to various topics. The power failed on the Workstation.

Using the Web console, I can see that ActiveMQ still thinks these subscribers are connected, based on the number of consumers shown and on the high temp message store being used. I had set for no producer flow control and set memory limits, so what I believe I am seeing is that ActiveMQ is spooling all messages to disk because it thinks the long dead subscribers are still connected and might eventually read them. It's been 30 days, and ActiveMQ still doesn't realize that these subscribers are no longer connected.

It there a way to configure ActiveMQ so that "undead" subscriber connections like these are eventually cleared automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the previous answer is basically correct, ActiveMQ does provide solutions for STOMP transports on the Broker to heart-beat connections, even if the client connects with STOMP v1.0.  I [blogged](http://timbish.blogspot.com/2012/05/whats-new-for-stomp-in-activemq-56.html) about this some time ago when ActiveMQ v5.6 was released, see the section on STOMP 1.0 default heartbeat configuration.  Another option is to set tcp keepAlive on for the transport and tune your OS to use a shorter default check interval, the default is usually around two hours.

Comment: I read your blog posting, the salient part of which is that the connector should be configured likestomp://0.0.0.0:0?transport.defaultHeartBeat=5000,0

Comment: I got interrupted before finishing my previous comment. A connector URI like the example given of `stomp://0.0.0.0:0?transport.defaultHeartBeat=5000,0` should time out a connection that is idle for more than 5000 milliseconds. I'm about to try this. If it works, it's just the kind of solution I was hoping for.

Comment: I tried the recommendation above, but it did not seem to work. I modified the connector in my `activemq.xml` to be `<transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?transport.defaultHeartBeat=900000,0"/>` and restarted ActiveMQ. Then I launched a Perl script that subscribes to some wildcarded topics. I say the number of consumers increase on the relevant topics as I expected. I am getting slow consumer advisories and the memory use is growing, according to the web console. But after 20 minutes, the number of consumers hasn't dropped and my memory use is still high.

Comment: Memory use is still high because ActiveMQ is holding messages on those topics because it assumes the subscribing Perl script will eventually read the messages, which it won't. I killed the Perl script and the number of consumers went down.

Comment: I realize I didn't properly mention that the Perl script connects and subscribes, but it does not read; it simply does a very long sleep.

Comment: I also didn't mention that I'm using ActiveMQ 5.8.0.

Comment: Maybe your Perl client is a v1.1 stomp client and its sending the heart-beats in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Though Stomp 1.1+ supports [Heartbeating](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#Heart-beating), Active MQ currently doesnt support [inactive consumer detection](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/stomp-uri-configuration.html) for Stomp. (usually achieved with *wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration*).

```
Be Careful:
These values are currently not supported but are planned for a later release
```

ActiveMQ supports it for Openwire though. i,e after the configured duration the consumer would be considered DEAD !